# PostgreSQL trigger if one of the columns have changed

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to keep track of changes on a table and store them in a corresponding history table after an UPDATE occurs if at least one of the fields has changed.

I have the following tables:

**tbl_employees**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_employees (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying NOT NULL
)
```

**tbl_employees_history**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_employees (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    employee_id NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying NOT NULL,
    changed_on timestamp NOT NULL
)
```

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_employee_changes() RETURNS trigger as 
$BODY$
BEGIN
     IF (NEW.last_name <> OLD.last_name) or (NEW.first_name <> OLD.first_name) THEN
     INSERT INTO tbl_employee_history(employee_id,last_name, first_name,changed_on)
     VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name, OLD.first_name,now());
     END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_log
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_employees
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_employee_changes();
```

So far so good, this thing just works. But I'm wondering if I have a table with lets say 15 columns, and I want to save a history record if one of the columns have changed. Do I have to repeat the IF statement over and over again for every field or is there some kind of trick to just check every column? That way I can just add a column to the table without the possibility to forget to change the trigger function.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_employee_changes() RETURNS trigger as 
$BODY$
BEGIN
     IF ?????there is one change on whatever column????? THEN
     INSERT INTO tbl_employee_history(employee_id,last_name, first_name,changed_on)
     VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name, OLD.first_name,now());
     END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can compare whole records:

```
if new <> old then ...
```

or

```
if new is distinct from old then ...
```

The second option is more general. Use the first one only when you are sure that the records cannot contain nulls.

Comment: ooh that's nice, didn't know that was possible! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I hope, it will be helpful for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_employee_changes() RETURNS trigger as 
$BODY$
BEGIN
     IF OLD!=NEW THEN
     INSERT INTO tbl_employee_history(employee_id,last_name, first_name,changed_on)
     VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name, OLD.first_name,now());
     END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I have tried it as well, and also works! But is there any difference between <> or != ?

Comment: != is alias of the <>.